How to find the maximum value of coefficient k that satisfies the condition?
The known equation is:
(1 + 62 x)^99 + (62 - x)^99 == a0 + a1  x + a2  x^2 + a3  x^3 + ... + 
 a99  x^99

And
a0, a1, a3, ..., a99 \[Element] Reals

When
ak < 0, k \[Element] Integers, 0 <= k <= 99

Find the maximum value of k that satisfies ak < 0, where k is an integer and k is between 0 and 99 inclusive.

The table function was used to list all the coefficients, but the maximum value of k that satisfies the condition was not determined.
Table["a" <> ToString[k] <> "=" <> 
  ToString[
   Coefficient[(1 + 62 x)^99 + (62 - x)^99 // Expand, x, k]], {k, 0, 
  99, 1}]

From the data generated above, only the maximum value of k that meets the condition can be viewed.

I don't see your effort in understanding the answers you've obtained: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/297718/1871 (-1)

You can use Sow and Reap:
p= (1 + 62 x)^99 + (62 - x)^99;
Reap[Table[Sow[j,Coefficient[p,x,j]],{j,0,99}],_?(#<0&),#2&][[2,-1]]

yields {49}

This finds positions of all negative coefficients. You want the last one. But since the position of coefficient's position is indexed from 1 to 100 and you want them 0 to 99 you need to subtract 1.
CoefficientList[(1 + 62 x)^99 + (62 - x)^99, x];
Position[%, x_ /; x < 0]
Last[%]-1


{{2},{4},{6},{8},{10},{12},{14},{16},{18},{20},{22},{24},{26},
{28},{30},{32},{34},{36},{38},{40},{42},{44},{46},{48},{50}}

{49}


Use user-defined ZipWithIndexStartsFrom0 and DropWhile.
Clear["Global`*"];
ZipWithIndexStartsFrom1 = MapIndexed[Labeled, #] &;
ZipWithIndexStartsFrom0 = MapIndexed[Labeled[#1, #2 - 1] &, #] &;
DropWhile = Drop[#, LengthWhile[#, #2]] &;

Table[Coefficient[(1 + 62 x)^99 + (62 - x)^99 // Expand, x, k], {k, 0, 99, 1}] 
// ZipWithIndexStartsFrom0
// Reverse 
// DropWhile[#, #[[1]] >= 0 &] & 
// TableForm

